# C++: How to write from a static function to a global variable

Tags: c++

I want to access a variable (through ctypes) which is supposed to be the result of a static void function, that is listening to broadcast.

So how do I get information out of a static function except using the "return" statement?

edit:

Here is an example code of what I mean:

```
class Foo{

int bar;

static void listener(){

bar = 3;

}

main(){
    listener();
    }

}
```

Comment: can't you just define it in the static function?

Comment: This is very unclear. What is this variable that you want to access and why can't you just write to it?

Comment: Please provide an example following these [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Some code to demonstrate what you want to do would be helpful

Comment: Hmmm, `main()` inside a class. Did someone just move from Java?

Comment: I need it to be in a class because I use ctypes.

Answer (score 1):

static method can only access static members:

```
class Foo {
    static int bar;
public:
    static void listener() { bar = 3; }
};

int Foo::bar = 0;

int main()
{
    Foo::listener();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your variable as `static`:

```
class Foo {

public:
   static int bar;

   static void listener() {

       bar = 3;
   }
};


int Foo::bar = 0;

main() {
    Foo::listener();
    }
    // now use Foo::bar. It's value is 3.
}
```

Heads up that the variable being `public` **and** `static` can be modified by everyone, not only by `Foo::listener`

Comment: ‘*the variable being static can be modified by everyone*’ What?!

Comment: @Biffen maybe my comment wasn't clear. I meant that from the `main()` you can change that value as well (being `public` and `static`) using for example `Foo::bar = 7;`